# Installed an extension rasvit Advanced Product Feeds on magento

Tags: magento, module, extension-methods

I installed an extension on magento store. Name of the extension is Mirasvit Advanced Product Feeds The extension was in a zip file. After installing the extension, I started a validation test for the installed extension from the admin panel and i got this error:

```
Table 'feedexport/feed' not exists Table 'feedexport/feed_history' not
exists Table 'feedexport/template' not exists Table 
'feedexport/custom_attribute' not exists Table 
'feedexport/performance_click' not exists Table 
'feedexport/performance_order' not exists Table 
'feedexport/performance_aggregated' not exists Table 'feedexport/rule' 
not exists Table 'feedexport/rule_product' not exists Table 
'feedexport/rule_feed' not exists Table 'feedexport/feed_product' not 
exists Table 'feedexport/mapping_category' not exists
```

I also check `core_resource` table and no `Mirasvit` extension related data found.

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?